# how to j2me app with external database

Tags: java-me

I am developing my final year project that is mobile based attendance management and tracking system, but I am confused to make GPRS connectivity between j2me mobile application and mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [j2mesamples](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/database-connection-using-j2me.html) if it would help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to connect to a mySql database directly. What you'd do instead, is to use a server-side scripting language, like e.g. PHP, to handle communications between your MIDlet and mySql.

You'll then have your MIDlet call PHP scripts like e.g.:

http://www.yoursite.com/insert.php?field1=some_value&field2=some_other_value

The PHP script will then get the values and insert into the database.

I've used this approach a few times for inserting and retrieving highscores for my games.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use drivers in between and make sure you have MySQL Workbench to work on the other side.